# Getting the Rendering time of a Unity Game scene on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rendering, render

How to get (and log) the **exact rendering time** (**the time required only by the rendering part** in unity) of a scene in unity game while running it on Android (**without using profiler** as profiler will add some extra overhead)

Comment: Any sort of monitoring is going to add an overhead, but granted that targeted monitoring should have a lesser impact.  How "exact" does it have to be?  Have you seen the lifecycle of a script: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html ?

Comment: yes. I have already seen the lifecycle. Can you suggest me any unity API to record only the rendering time? 1/fps is also giving overall frame time including rendering time. While running on the desktop in the stat window its giving CPU thread & render thread time but how to log that render thread and CPU thread time in a file while running on android?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any available API call.  Time.unscaledDeltaTime is the real-time between calls to `Update()` (so includes gpu and cpu processing).  The best I can offer is, based off of the lifecycle linked in OP's comments, start a timer immediately before the Render part and stop it immediately after using:

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    StartCoroutine(RenderTimer());
}

IEnumerator RenderTimer()
{
    var started = YourHiResTimerHere.Now;

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var ended = YourHiResTimerHere.Now;
    var gpuWait = ended - started;
}
```

Keep in mind that most C# timers have terrible resolution (about 20ms at best)

Comment: Want to know another thing, if my phone has a vsync count of 60Hz (that means 16.67 ms) but if my lightweight rendering takes < 16 ms. Is it possible to detect those using the methodology you described? Just want to know (how vsync of android platform affects)

Comment: Don't know. Sorry.